# Php mysqli query with array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have database with users, I want to show results without users that i have id's in array.
How should i do it, any ideas?

```
<?php
include_once "dbh.php";
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['userId'];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$noid = array("8","9","10");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUsers != '$noid' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
if ($resultCheck> 0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['nick'];
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUsers NOT IN(8,9,10) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`

Comment: is there any way to do it in array, bcs this array will auto expand

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Additionally, be warned that this code is open for SQL injection

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `not in`,

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUsers not in(" . join(",",$noid) . ") ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; "
```

Answer (score -2):

Your query should be:

```
'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (' . implode(',', $noid) . ')';
```

IF you have 'LIMIT 1' there you'll only get one result back.